# CMB2 - array_search or in_array from repeat_group and comma separated values

Tags: plugins, plugin-options

I have this data coming from `$myoptions = my_get_option('my_repeat_group');`

`$p = 'T1X 0L6'; // find me`

`print_r($myoptions) =`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[region_name] => Alberta 
[postal_codes] => T1X 0L3,T1X 0L4,T1X 0L5,T1X 0L6,T1X 0L7 
[region_discount] => .5 )
[1] => Array ( 
[region_name] => Ontario 
[postal_codes] => T1M 0W3,T1M 0W4,T1M 0W5,T1M 0W6,T1M 0W7 
[region_discount] => .25 ) )
```

```
foreach ( $myoptions as $key => $value ) {
   if ( in_array($p, $value['postal_codes'] ) {
      // need to know $key of which array the $p was found,
      // in this case, I would like to find [0]
   }
}
```

I would like to find `$p` within `$value['postal_codes']`, and when I do find it, return the key in which it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$value['postal_codes']` is not an `array` it is a `string`, you either need to explode it like:

```
foreach ( $myoptions as $key => $value ) {
   if (in_array($p,explode(","$value['postal_codes']){
      // need to know $key of which array the $p was found, in this case I would like to find [0]
   }
}
```

Or search on the string

```
foreach ( $myoptions as $key => $value ) {
   if (strstr($value['postal_codes'],$p){

   }
}
```

Or the most efficient way would be use array_search on the exploded like so:

```
foreach($myoptions as $key => $options) {
   $keys_containing_p[$key] = array_search($p,explode(",",$options['postal_codes']));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Liam!  the most efficient way worked great!  it is returning the $key I am looking for... solid!